# Voiceover and Text To Speech - differences in pronunciation

Tags: accessibility, text-to-speech, voiceover

I've been playing around a little with both VoiceOver and the Text to speech functionality on my mac. I've noticed a few differences in the way numbers and punctuation is pronounced. For example the sentence "the year was 1978", is read out perfectly when I highlight it and use text to speech. With Voiceover however, it reads "the year was one nine seven eight".

How can I tell screen readers that I want something pronounced in a certain way? Is there ARIA attributes I can add for this kind of behaviour?

It is not just dates and years but prices and punctuation as well (and probably a lot of other things!).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can control speech output with the APIs currently available.

I assume that you are talking about HTML page as you referenced ARIA attributes. WAI ARIA does not have attributes to control the screen reading. I believe W3C is coming up with Text-to-Speech synthesizing markup language (SSML) to provide better control over speech output.

If your issue is related to native Mac OS application screens, you can check out [Apple's Speech Synthesis APIs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/SpeechSynthesisProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004365-CH1-SW1).

The Apple VoiceOver as well as Microsoft Windows Narrator are very basic screen readers with little or no intelligence built in. Apple's text-to-speech is little advanced but it still lags behind commercial screen readers like JAWS. But good thing is that users with impaired vision typically have good screen readers which can read your content appropriately.

Comment: I totally object that VoiceOver is a very basic screen reader. VoiceOver is a very advanced screen reader, incomparable with Narrator by a long shot. Screen reader quality is mostly in how reliably and easily it allows the user to traverse the UI. While speech output is one aspect of this, it is far from the whole picture. The whole picture includes consistency of keyboard shortcuts, national support, conceptual easiness of working with it, ways to workaround problems/bugs etc. While JAWS added e.g. some setting to read numbers containing dashes as digits, it's still only (heuristic) guessing.

Comment: Well, I should have used the words "very basic" carefully. I meant to use them only in comparison with more popular tools such as JAWS. I do agree that it is better when compared to MS Narrator but it does fall short when compared with its commercial counterparts.

Answer (score 0):

Common speech synthesizers allow their clients to configure whether numbers will be read as words or spelled-out (both on a global default and per-specific-case setting). E.g. Apple's speech synthesis API propagates this possibility using the `NSSpeechNumberModeProperty` property. VoiceOver users can then set only global (or at best per-app) default in VoiceOver Utility > Verbosity > Text > "Read numbers as:".

Now if you want to influence how screen readers should pronounce numbers in web content, there is a [CSS Speech Module](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/). It defines the [`speak-as`](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-speech/#speak-as) property, which can have a value of `normal` or `digits`.

However whether such CSS value will be respected by a combination of particular version of particular screen reader and particular version on a particular browser running of particular version of particular OS is a thing you have to try yourself. The accessibility APIs on OS X currently have no way to specify pronunciation of digits in the returned strings, so if it worked for WebKit, it would have to be using some private extension to those public accessibility APIs. I just tried on OS X 10.9.3 and this does not work.

If I had to guess, you would be lucky to find a combination of screen reader / browser / OS where this would be implemented as of now. But this is just speculation.